# deleting binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, destructor

I am trying to delete the whole binary search tree ( every node in the tree), which one of these functions do you think will work better?

```
private:
    struct Node {
        string value;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };
    Node* root;

public:
    BST() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    ~BST() {
        delete root->left;
        delete root->right;
    }
```

or:

```
...
    void destroyTree (Node*& tree) {
        while (tree != NULL) {
            tree = tree->left;
            delete tree;
        }
        while (tree != NULL) {
            tree = tree->right;
            delete tree;
        }
        delete tree;
    }
```

Comment: Please add the tag **'C'** to maximize the number of viewers.

Comment: @J.Piquard If you can recognise the language you might as well tag it yourself

Comment: @Bergi, in fact the tag **'C++'** is the right one with the partial `class BST` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the proposed destructor `~BST()` nor the proposed function `destroyTree()`of the `class BST` will delete the BST instance and will be better than the other.

**Explanation 1** - what the destructor `~BST()` is doing ?

> The proposed source is simple `delete root->left;` followed by `delete
>   root->right;` and will delete only 2 nodes of the BinarySearchTree.

1. The node `root` is not check with NULL and otherwise is never deleted,
2. The node `root->left` is not check with NULL too,
3. The node `root->right` is not check with NULL too,

**Explanation 2** - what the function `destroyTree()` is doing ?

> Two while-loops to try the exploration of the tree, one for the left
>   branch and one for the right branch. The condition `(tree != NULL)` is
>   present only to exit from the loop but doesn't check if the current
>   node could be deleted.

1. With the left loop, only `->left` nodes of the `root->left` will be deleted until `tree->left == NULL` and **CRASH** when trying to `delete tree;`,
2. Even after adding a `if (tree==NULL) break;` to exit from the loop before calling the `delete tree;` a new **CRASH** in the right loop,
3. And the last `delete tree;` is a non-sense because at this position, `tree` is always '== NULL`.

**Bonus Solution** - based to a modification of the function `destroyTree()`.

> A recursive function will be the simplest way to delete all created
>   and inserted nodes. But be aware with the size of the BinarySearchTree
>   and especially the deepest branch.

```
void destroyTree(Node *cur_node) {
    if (cur_node!=NULL) {
        // explore and delete on left
        destroyTree(cur_node->left); // recursive-call
        // explore and delete on right
        destroyTree(cur_node->right); // recursive-call
        // delete each node
        delete cur_node;
    }
}
```